# Linux x86_64 Assembly examples of threading/sys_clone()

Tags: linux, multithreading, assembly, x86-64

from the clone(2) manpage

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html

```html
       long clone(unsigned long flags, void *child_stack,
                 void *ptid, void *ctid,
                 struct pt_regs *regs);
```

it's not obvious how you specify the function using the bare syscall (not libc) and also how you set up "struct pt_regs *regs" in assembly (...do you somehow include the IP as a register in a stack of registers [arranged how?] pointed to by "*regs" which thus specifies the call address?)

I've searched for any pertinent examples.  Can anyone point to examples or clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not obvious, unless you know where to look.  This is for 32 bit syscalls:

```
eax = 120 (syscall number for sys_clone)
ebx = unsigned long flags
ecx = void *child_stack
edx = void *ptid
esi = void *ctid
edi = struct pt_regs *regs
```

Then an `int 80H`

http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ and search for `clone`

For 64bit syscalls:
http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64

And then look at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h for the definition of the pt_regs structure

Anything else, just read the man pages for clone and the info for the params are laid out.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks, @Gunner.  On reading your answer I realized I could have remembered the beauty of open source and simply done:  

    `grep -r pt_regs /usr/include/*`    

and then seen 

    `unsigned long ip;`